# copy-paste tables from word to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste

I have a word document which is updated periodically.  I can go into that Word document, select the contents of an entire table and copy, then go into an Excel spreadsheet and paste it.  It's screwed up; however, I fix it as follows:

```
    sht.Cells.UnMerge
    sht.Cells.ColumnWidth = 14
    sht.Cells.RowHeight = 14
    sht.Cells.Font.Size = 10
```

This manual copy-paste works regardless of whether the table is has merged fields.
Then I can start to manipulate it manually: parsing, checking, computations, etc.

I can do this one table at a time, but it's tedious and of course error prone.

I want to automate this.  I found some code:

```
Sub read_word_document()

Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordApp As Word.Application

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = False

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("Z:\mydir\myfile1.DOC", ReadOnly:=True)


j = 0
For i = 1 To WordDoc.Tables.Count
    DoEvents
    Dim s As String
    s = WordDoc.Tables(i).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
        Debug.Print i, s
        WordDoc.Tables(i).
        Set sht = Sheets("temp")
        'sht.Cells.Clear
        sht.Cells(1, 1).Select
        sht.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

    End If
Next i

WordDoc.Close
WordApp.Quit

GoTo done

ErrClose:
  On Error Resume Next

ErrHandler:

Debug.Print Err.Description

On Error GoTo 0

done:

End Sub
```

Of course this would just overwrite the same sheet again and again - and that's okay. This is just a test.  The problem is this will work for those tables that do not have merged cells.  However, it fails if the table has merged cells.  I have no control over the file I get.  It contains almost a hundred tables.  Is there a way to do the copy paste the EXACT WAY that I do when I perform the operation manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub read_word_document()

Const DOC_PATH As String = "Z:\mydir\myfile1.DOC"

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
Dim rng As Range, t As Word.Table

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = False
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(DOC_PATH, ReadOnly:=True)

    Set sht = Sheets("Temp")
    Set rng = sht.Range("A1")
    sht.Activate

    For Each t In WordDoc.Tables
        t.Range.Copy
        rng.Select
        rng.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, _
                    DisplayAsIcon:=False
        With rng.Resize(t.Rows.Count, t.Columns.Count)
            .Cells.UnMerge
            .Cells.ColumnWidth = 14
            .Cells.RowHeight = 14
            .Cells.Font.Size = 10
        End With

        Set rng = rng.Offset(t.Rows.Count + 2, 0)
    Next t
    WordDoc.Close
    WordApp.Quit
End Sub
```