# Import data and text format from word table to excel with excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

How do I import data and text format from word table to excel with excel-vba.
I have here a code example from what I tried so far if I import a word file.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
    Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
    Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

    With wdDoc
        TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
        If TableNo = 0 Then
            MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
            vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
        ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
            TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
            "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
        End If
        With .tables(TableNo)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
            Next iRow
        End With
    End With

    Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: [Does the following feed not help you? If not, please explain in less vague terms what you're trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999081/copy-paste-tables-from-word-to-excel)

Answer (score 0):

To import from Word to Excel, try the following.

```
Sub WordToExcel()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim x As Integer
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim temp As String

Set wdApp = New Word.Application
'initialise counter
x = 1
'search for first file in directory
strFolder = "C:\Test\"
strFilename = Dir(strFolder & "*.doc")
'amemd folder name
Do While strFilename <> ""
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strFolder & strFilename)
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 0) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 1) = temp
'etc
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 2) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 4).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 3) = temp

wdDoc.Close
x = x + 1
strFilename = Dir
Loop
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```